# overflow issues with flex using div

Tags: html, css

Ok so I run into a problem with flexbox, when I set the container to display: flex; and set the flex direction to row to make it so it can take up as much as it needs to so it can appear next to each other, But when it does the first div overflows into the body and I don't now why. I didn't set any child or id but I used the :nth-child() to select them both of the div, am wondering if it its the reason for the overflow or isn't because of the div.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300&display=swap');
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
    font-size: 62.2%;
    font-family: Roboto, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;

}

.containerFlex {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}

div:nth-child(1) {
    background-color: aqua;
}


div:nth-child(2) {
    background-color: lightcoral;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>FlexBox model</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Flexbox.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="containerFlex">
      <div>div 1</div>
      <div>div 2</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood well your problem, setting `flex-grow:1` to each `div` will solve your problem, and each would take 1/2 of the available width, like so:

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300&display=swap");

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  font-size: 62.2%;
  font-family: Roboto, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.containerFlex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  border: 1px solid;
}

div {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

div:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: aqua;
}

div:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: lightcoral;
}
```

```html
<div class="containerFlex">
  <div>div 1</div>
  <div>div 2</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The first div in nth Child is a containerFlex div, which is why it doesn't work properly. add classes to the inner divs and this will work better and correctly

```
<div class="containerFlex">
   <div class="div1">div 1</div>
   <div class="div2">div 2</div>
</div>

.div1 {
    background-color: aqua;
}
.div2{
    background-color: lightcoral;
}
```

You can also try this way without changing your code

```
.containerFlex div:nth-child(1) {
    background-color: aqua;
}
.containerFlex div:nth-child(2) {
    background-color: lightcoral;
}
```

Comment: wait should should i have wrap it in a inner div

Comment: Because the name itself says that it is looking for the first div in the body

Comment: I added a solution for your code, you can try it, it should work

Comment: ahhh i see so i could have selected the parent and the div but to increase the specificity and to say that I want to directly to it

Comment: Then add a unique class to this div and write properties to it

Comment: ok i get it but am still shaking my head why does it does select to first div in the body directly after containerflex even its a flex item of the flexcontainer

Comment: Try add justify-content: center to . containerFlex. in this way all content be in center

Comment: wait so  by the first div is flex container.div right is it treating the first div of the containerflex as the body

Comment: so couldnt  i just said that the first nth(2) and the second can be nth(3) since all of them is div

Comment: Yes, in case there are no more divs on the page, but it's better to just add classes and thus write values ​​to them